# Sorting Arrays in Arraylist in reverse order Java

Tags: java, arrays, sorting, arraylist

I have made an Arraylist with Arrays and I would like to sorted it by a first item in array in reverse order.
For example:

```
ArrayList<int[]> arr = new ArrayList<>();
arr.add[1,500,20];
arr.add[5,30,60];
arr.add[2,10,20];
```

and I'd like to sorted like this:

```
[5,30,60],[2,100,20],[1,500,300]
```

Is there any option in Java to do that? I know about Comparator, but I don't know how to use it in this case.

Thanks for help

Comment: so you want it sorted based on first entry in each array?

Comment: *"I know about Comparator, but i don't know how to use it in this case."* There are many examples and tutorials out there. Have you checked them? What exactly is still unclear?

Comment: Yes there's a way and you should try it. Also, you didn't specify *how* each array is sorted, i.e. Is it by the first element and then second and so on?

Comment: @Idos It doesn't look like the arrays itself should be sorted. They stay as they are.

Comment: @Tom that's not what I asked..

Comment: No, i want to sorted only by first element in array, it is only bad example... I will change it

Comment: so what you're actually asking is... how to use a Comparator? There's a tutorial on that somewhere...

Comment: I am asking how to sorted. I red few tutorials but i dont know how to use it on this case.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can implement a customer `Comparator` and pass it to `Collections.sort()` along with the `ArrayList`.

```
ArrayList<int[]> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
arrayList.add(new int[]{1,500,20});
arrayList.add(new int[]{5,30,60});
arrayList.add(new int[]{2,10,20});

// Custom `Comparator` to sort the list of int [] on the basis of first element.
Collections.sort(arrayList, new Comparator<int[]>() {
  @Override
  public int compare(int[] a1, int[] a2) {
    return a2[0] - a1[0];  // the reverse order is define here.
  }
});

// Output to STDOUT
for(int a[] : arrayList) {
  for (int i: a){
    System.out.print(i + "\t");
  }
  System.out.println();
}
```

Output:

```
5   30  60  
2   10  20  
1   500 20
```

---

**Disclaimer:** The code above does not handle corner cases like `null` and `empty array (zero size)`. Please handle them appropriately as per your needs.

Comment: I suppose a check for empty might be in order in that compare - that's the first test case I'd run...

Comment: @Jan Yeah, That could be required. I did not do that, so the OP can learn and handle little more. I just provide a basic on how to write a custom comparator. `null` and `empty array` check are missing in this.

Comment: which might be a frustrating enterprise as these questions seem to be closed as duplicate before they're even submitted ;-)

Comment: @Jan I hope you understand that, people are here to help, when you stuck, I guess not for writing a code with all the corner cases.

Comment: yes I know, please don't take offense. It's just with a comment like `//You need to make this bullet-proof` the reader (and all future readers) will know not to take this code as-is.

Comment: @Jan I guess a **Disclaimer** message is enough for the future/current readers.

Answer (score 1):

Using lambdas (Java 8):

```
        final List<int[]> result = arr.stream()
            .sorted((a, b) -> Integer.valueOf(b[0]).compareTo(Integer.valueOf(a[0])))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```